# Contar quantos nomes iguais existem dentro de um JSON e mostrar em tela em NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Tenho um json que tem nomes de pessoas iguais, e necessito contar quantos nomes estão repetidos e dar uma soma total. Fiz de uma forma, mas ele esta contando a quantidade de caracteres que tem no nome e não esta contando a quantidade total de nomes iguais.

```
{
      "candidates": [    

        {

          "CLIENT_ID": "Dread Pirate Alannah Company",
          "VALUE": 0,
          "LOST_VALUE": 45,
        },
        {

          "CLIENT_ID": "Dread Pirate Alannah Company",  
          "VALUE": 56.25,
          "LOST_VALUE": 0,
        },
        {

          "CLIENT_ID": "Dread Pirate Alannah Company",
          "VALUE": 45,
          "LOST_VALUE": 0,
        },
        {

          "CLIENT_ID": "Wis Company",
          "VALUE": 45,
          "LOST_VALUE": 0,
        }
      ]
    }
```

Código que apliquei

```
function allRejected(arr){

    var contador = 0;

    if (arr !== undefined){
        for (var item = 0; item < arr.length; item++){
            if (item !== undefined && arr.indexOf(item)){
                contador ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return contador;
}
```

Comment: @AndréMartins por que? O que tem de errado nele?

Comment: me equivoquei eram 2 da manhã rsrs @Costamilam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há vários problemas no seu código, nem imagino como chegou a isso, parece que misturou várias formas de se fazer algo parecido com o que quer

Vou colocar uma solução comentada para entender

```js
function allRejected(arr) {
  //O contador passa a ser um objeto, onde as chaves serão os nomes e os valores serão o número de repetições
  var contador = {};

  //Removi o "!== undefined" para ele verificar se for diferente de null, false ou 0 também
  if (arr) {
    //Percorre o array com a sintaxe "for of"
    for (var item of arr) {
      //Remoção do "!== undefined" novamente, 
      if (item) {
        //Se o contador não possui uma propriedade com o nome igual a item.CLIENT_ID
        if (contador[item.CLIENT_ID] === undefined) {
          //Cria essa propriedade e atribui o tamanho do array filtrado
          //A função filter irá iterar sobre o array e remover o que o callback retornar false sem alterar o array original
          contador[item.CLIENT_ID] = arr.filter(function(item2) {
            //Se CLIENT_ID do loop "for of" for igual ao do filter retorna true, se não, false
            return item.CLIENT_ID === item2.CLIENT_ID
            //A função filter retornará um array com os itens que tiverem o mesmo CLIENT_ID, para saber quantos são, basta acessar o tamanho (length)
          }).length;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //Retorna o objeto que contém o número de repetições 
  return contador;
}

//Mostra no console o resultado
console.log(allRejected([
  {
    "CLIENT_ID": "Dread Pirate Alannah Company",
    "VALUE": 0,
    "LOST_VALUE": 45,
  },
  {
    "CLIENT_ID": "Dread Pirate Alannah Company",
    "VALUE": 56.25,
    "LOST_VALUE": 0,
  },
  {
    "CLIENT_ID": "Dread Pirate Alannah Company",
    "VALUE": 45,
    "LOST_VALUE": 0,
  },
  {
    "CLIENT_ID": "Wis Company",
    "VALUE": 45,
    "LOST_VALUE": 0,
  }
]))
```

Comment: Fiz alguns testes com este trecho de código que você me passou e vi que tem dois problemas(pelo menos acredito que sejam), um é que o for of não aceita o .length e o filter esta me informando que arr.filter não é uma função ( **arr.filter is not a function** )

Comment: O primeiro foi erro de digitação meu, o segundo pode ser que você tenha passado o objeto, em vez da propriedade `candidates` que é um array. Editei a resposta com um executável

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = {
  "candidates": [    

    {

      "CLIENT_ID": "Dread Pirate Alannah Company",
      "VALUE": 0,
      "LOST_VALUE": 45,
    },
    {

      "CLIENT_ID": "Dread Pirate Alannah Company",  
      "VALUE": 56.25,
      "LOST_VALUE": 0,
    },
    {

      "CLIENT_ID": "Dread Pirate Alannah Company",
      "VALUE": 45,
      "LOST_VALUE": 0,
    },
    {

      "CLIENT_ID": "Wis Company",
      "VALUE": 45,
      "LOST_VALUE": 0,
    }
  ]
}
```

Pega todos os nomes:

```
const names = data.candidates.map( candidate => candidate.CLIENT_ID )
```

Filtra os nomes repetidos:

```
const uniqNames = names.filter((name, index, self) => self.indexOf(name) === index)
```

Passa por todos os nomes e verifica quantos nomes de cada existem:

```
let result = [];
uniqNames.forEach( uName => {
    names.forEach( name => {
        if (name == uName) {
            result[uName] = (result[uName] > 0 ? result[uName] : 0)  + 1
        }
    })
})

// result: [Dread Pirate Alannah Company: 3, Wis Company: 1]
```

Você também pode criar uma implementação que vá retirando do array `names` os registros que já foram contados.